# Let $e$ and $n$ be positive integers. Suppose $e$ and $φ(n)$ are relatively prime. Prove if $x^e ≡ 1\bmod(n)$, then $x ≡ 1\bmod(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

My thoughts so far:

Since $φ(n)$ is always even, $e$ must be odd $\implies e$ can be written as $2d + 1$.
$\implies x^{2d+1} - 1 = kn$

However, I don't know how to proceed from here. Any tips?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question: Good Titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144). Your question should not refer to information in the title and try to make your title more interesting.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt sorry, i will keep that in mind

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we know $x^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$, so we can use that, since now we know for all positive integers $a,b$ that
$$(x^{\phi(n)})^a(x^e)^b\equiv1\mod n$$
which can be rewritten to
$$x^{a\phi(n)+be}\equiv1\mod n$$

for every $a,b$. Now since $\phi(n)$ and $e$ are coprime, we can find $a,b$ such that $a\phi(n)+be=1$, and so if we pick those, the congruence reads

$$x\equiv 1\mod n$$

exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Isn't this answer wrong since Euler Theory only works if $x$ and $n$ are coprime? That is not necessarily the case

Comment: Well, the fact that there exists an $e$ with $x^e\equiv 1\mod n$ implies $\gcd(x,n)=1$.